# PHPmailer and attachment form - not sending

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

hi i've got question i've made simple form with attachment input and i want to send this attachment via mail in to my mailbox but i allways see the error that attached file isn;t found on filesystem.

this is the code in php:

```
<? 
   require('phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From= $_POST['email'];
    $mail->FromName= $_POST['contact'];
    $mail->Sender= $_POST['email'];
    $mail->AddReplyTo("xxxx", "Porozumienie");

    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxx");
    $mail->Subject = "Your invoice";

    $mail->IsHTML(false); 

    $plik_tmp = $_FILES[contr][tmp_name];
    $plik_nazwa = $_FILES[contr][name];
    $plik_rozmiar = $_FILES[contr][size];

    $target_path = "uploads/";

    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['contr']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['contr']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['contr']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

    $mail->AddAttachment(basename($target_path));

    $mail->Body = "Please find your invoice attached.";
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "Error sending";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Letter is sent";
       unlink($target_path);
    } 
?>
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Check your path in require('phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php').If your file is in other folder then  you should write require('../phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@arclite: Since you are getting attachment not found error. 
Check your upload folder permission and make it writable if not.

@pari: Since he is using "require" the php will throw an error if the required file doesn't exit. So it cannot be a problem.

Comment: i added chmod 777 to uploads/ folder and im getting error while sending image im getting this `Array
(
    [name] => map_point.png
    [type] => image/png
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/php2n1DzO
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 1380
)

The file map_point.png has been uploaded,
Mailer Error
Description:
Could not find map_point.png file on filesystem`